# RxSwift - withLatestFrom combining values from both observables

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I want to achieve result like this:

```
L -1-2-3------4------5-6-7-8----
R ---------A------B----------C--

O ---------A3-----B4---------C8
```

So basically something like withLatestFrom but combining values from both observables (like combine latest).

I guess there is no ready operator for that. Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just use resulting selector from your `withLatestFrom`. The overloaded implementation without closure simply ignores first observable. For example:

```
Observable.just("one")
  .withLatestFrom(Observable.just(1)) 
  { oneAsString, oneAsInt in return (oneAsString, oneAsInt) }
```

Comment: Yep, works like a charm. I was not aware of this overloaded version. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Short version where your R = input.r and L = input.l

```
let output = input.r
.withLatestFrom(input.l) { ($0, $1) }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using `combineLatest` with `distinctUntilChanged` followed by a `map`.

```
Observable.combineLatest(L,R) { lhs, rhs in
     return (lhs, rhs)
}
.distinctUntilChanged { last, new in 
     return last.1 != new.1
}
.map { combined in
     //Do your thing to create the combination
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can just swap R and L observables:

```
    R
       .withLatestFrom(L) { ($0, $1) }
       .subscribe(onNext: { r, l in
           print("\(r)\(l)")
       })
```

So the R will be the triggering observable and it will always take the last value from L